# Teb Local Planner Weight Parameters

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on teb local planner but i didn't understand what weight parameters really do? Can someone briefly summarize please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403194/teb-local-planner-weight-parameters/) by [anonymous60874](https://answers.ros.org/users/60874/anonymous60874/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner The wiki gives brief summary of parameters

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0